# how to migrate wordpress to mangoblog?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm now trying to migrate wordpress posts to mangoBlog 1.5. But, I can't find any options in MangoBlog Admin.

Comment: Hmm... this is not really a programming question, is it?

Comment: There seems to be an importer, though: See e.g. http://www.mangoblog.org/forums/messages.cfm?threadid=D6C35D2B-3048-2A53-70A185B1D808F224

Comment: @Pekka Thanks, I've already browsed this thread. I feel it would be in MangoBlog's previous version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this moment, you have to import it while you are installing Mango (not after you have created the blog).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a custom script to migrate from MangoBlog to Wordpress. Should be pretty simple to reverse the process.

http://www.placona.co.uk/317/coldfusion/migrating-mango-blog-to-wordpress/

Comment: It's nice but Mango to wordpress isn't that much possible.  I think, I need to create custom script for importing witth cffeed or cfhttp.

Answer (score 0):

I recall there is an import script built into the Mango installer.